# Storage space running out

Tags: motorola-moto-g

I got my Moto G (2nd gen) just one month ago and ever since I got it its been this annoying notification that won't go away saying that my "Storage Space is running Out" and that "Some systems functions may not work" ... I don't know what to do

I ALREADY
-took half my photos of my phone & put them on my computer
-deleted half my apps
-and cleared data on the remaining apps I have
And it won't let me download any other apps, if .... Keeps stating I don't have enough room. Some one please please help!!!!

Comment: It's hard to provide a definitive answer when we don't know what's causing the increased use of your storage space. For starters I would recommend installing an app like [Disk Usage](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.diskusage) that can help you analyze which files and folders occupy your file system.

Comment: can you share your screenshots of storage and application installed...this problem can be solved by removing cache

Answer (score 1):

Go to settings --> Application manager, now you see which apps which holding more space (which is specified under every application) if it's some google services app which can't be uninstalled click **unistall updates** and then
Go to play store settings --> Auto-update apps --> Do not auto-update apps to avoid facing these problems in future.

This may help you in losing storage space for nothing. Hope this helps.. :)